# Recycle Bin Deleted Sites is showing "-" under the "Deleted by"

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, delete

We have noted that one of our SharePoint online Team Sites has been removed and when we check the Recycle Bin for the deleted sites we found the site there, but we are unable to know who has deleted the site as the "Deleted By" is showing "-", as follow:-

[image]

any idea how we can get the deleted by?

Answer (score 1):

Under normal circumstances, there will indeed be a short delay. It Will appear after a while.You can also check the audit log reports for it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after deleting a site collection, initially I saw [**Deleted by**] column was empty. However, after sometime when I refreshed the page, it's showing "**System Account**". I guess, the actual deletion is done by some behind-the-scene flow/job

[image]